# PowerShell operators, select before first period

Tags: powershell, operators

I need some help with operators in PowerShell please. I'm trying to select anything before the first period.

For example, filename contains string `first.last@domain.com` and I'd like to select `first`

```
$path = "c:\file.txt"
$Firstname = get-content -path $path | where-object {$_<WHAT SHOULD I USE HERE?>}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `split` method -

```
$Firstname = (get-content -path $path).Split(".")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `-replace` and some `RegEx`

```
$path = "c:\file.txt"
$Firstname = get-content -path $path | where-object { $_ -replace '^(.*?)\..*$', '$1' }
```